# Spring4 with Hibernate4 fails in standalone process

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-4.x, spring-4

I'm failling to use Spring4 togather with Hibernate4 in a standalone process (no container like tomcat, WAS, ...)

How can I use Hibernate4, Spring4 and Spring data repositories togather in a standalone process?

However I confiugre Spring I allways get the same exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:118)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
```

When googling for this, I get pointet to some information about `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform` and the docu for Hibernate 4.3 is here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#services-JtaPlatform

But the only option I see for my case would be `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform` but this still leads to the same error.

Here is my Spring config:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xx.yy" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.xx.zz.respositories"></jpa:repositories>

<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/culture" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="culture.matching.index.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Need to remove all the references to JTA - you have no JTA container. Also, why are you still using XML if you are using Spring 4?

Comment: Which references do you mean? The only reference to JTA I see in the config is 'jtaDataSource' and even if I change this to 'dataSource' the same problem exists.

Comment: [Found a decent tutorial](http://geowarin.github.io/2013/01/21/using-spring-data-jpa-in-a-java-se-environment-and-run-tests-with-dbunit/) that should get you up and running.

Comment: I would urge you to take a look at Spring Boot which can vastly reduce the amount of configuration you need to write for Spring applications (whether they are web or standalone application). Take a look at this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple

Comment: @BoristheSpider strange enough, the tutorial you'r pointing to also uses the 'LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'

Comment: @domi yeah, I noticed that.

Comment: Another great resource for checking out how Spring Boot will help you remove most (almost all that this) Spring configururation, check out this guide http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @BoristheSpider but I got it wokring with the javaconfig of the tutorial you pointed me to - many thanks!!!

Comment: @geoand thanks for the hint to spring-boot - I might actually do that, but It will require quite some refactoring

Comment: @domi If you are still in this initial stages of development and can manage the cost of some refactoring, it is probably worth it to check out boot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @geoand helped a lot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple 
I therefore moved from XML to Java config

Comment: Hi, your reference is dead. Please follow the rules - you always must directly include the important citations. Only prooves and alternatives are what you can leave out of the answer.